# why cannot directly use print(something.sort())?

Tags: python, printing

I am a python beginner, could someone help to explain why this print() doesn't work, and python prints me a **None** result?

```
list =['a','c','d','e']
print(list.sort())
```

so if i make a extra step, i can get the results:

```
list =['a','c','d','e']
list.sort()
print(list)
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

`list.sort()`  is a modifying function that modifies the list. It is not a list itself. `print(list.sort())` will get you `None` since there is no list to return from this function.

Answer (score 1):

`list.sort()` modifies the list in place, meaning that it sorts the list in its current location in memory without returning anything.

What you want is `sorted(list)`, which makes a copy of the list, sorts it, and then returns it.

Answer (score 0):

`list.sort()` doesn't store your sorted list in a new variable, instead, it modifies the list directly, think of it as a **procedure**. you can still keep your **original list** by making a **copy** of it, just use the build-it `copy` method

**Code:**

```
list =['c','a','d','e']

# saving a copy of our original list
originList = list.copy()
print("original list:",originList)

# sorting our list
list.sort()
print("sorted list:",list)
```

**Output:**

```
oiginal list: ['c', 'a', 'd', 'e']  # the copy (now it's the original)
sorted list: ['a', 'c', 'd', 'e']    # the original (now it's sorted)
```

Comment: Notice: I don't recommend naming variables like pre-defined python keywords such as list/tuple etc... instead, capitalize the first character or add a number in the end of the name, otherwise errors may occur

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question implied by what you're trying to do:

If you want a one-liner to print the sorted list, you can use

```py
print(sorted(the_list))
```

Note that `sorted(the_list)` returns a new, sorted version of `the_list`, and `the_list` remains unmodified afterwards.